# Splitting training data with equal number rows for each classes

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a very large dataset of about 314554097 rows and 3 columns. The third column is the class. The dataset has two class 0 and 1. I need split the data into test and training data. To split the data I can use

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split . 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.75, random_state = 0)
```

But, The dataset contains about 99 percent of class 0 and only 1 percent of class 1. In the training dataset, I need an equal number of class 0 and class 1 say 30000 rows of both classes. How can I do it?

Comment: @ScottBoston I checked the stratify parameter. It says if y has 99 percent of 0 and 1 percent of 1. The division will also have 99 percent of 0 and 1 percent of 1. But I need an equal amount of both 50-50.

Comment: Check out this library: https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be searching for solutions to handle imbalanced data. Here are some of methods you can follow.

1. Resampling: (Over sampling of minority class data points or Under sampling of majority class data points)

   > In your case, class 1 is minority class
2. Giving more weightage to minority class depending on the ratio of class imbalance
3. Choose right performance metric.

But still if you need 30k of class 1 & class 0 data points, try this:

```
X_train_sample_class_1 = X_train[X_train['third_column_name'] == 1][:30000]
X_train_sample_class_0 = X_train[X_train['third_column_name'] == 0][:30000]
```

Now you can combine `X_train_sample_class_1` & `X_train_sample_class_0` to form a new dataset which has balanced dataset

Answer (score 0):

When I tried the folowing:

```
X_train_sample_class_1 = X_train[X_train['third_column_name'] == 1][:30000]
X_train_sample_class_0 = X_train[X_train['third_column_name'] == 0][:30000]
```

the data frames are empty without values. How can I split with values, please?

Comment: Hi there, Consider posting a new question to get answers.