# Sklearn: Take only few records from each target class

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I have a large dataset with multi-class classification ( 3 classes), I want to take sub-sample of data i.e take 200 records belonging to each class and the upon that data, I want split the data.

Say the 3 classes are `cat`, `dog`, `cow`. I want to apply a split on the subset of data where there are 200 records selected out of a large dataset for each of the class `cat`, `dog`, `cow` to train the ML model.

- cat - 200 observations
- dog - 200 observations
- cow - 200 observations

This is the code line for splitting the data:

```
# split data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, stratify = y, test_size = 0.3, 
                                                          random_state = 42)
```

How can I select `X` and `y` such that it has 200 records for each of the class?

Comment: If you're using pandas DataFrames', you can do for example `df.groupby('class').sample(200, random_state=42)`

Comment: Please see this discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52279834/splitting-training-data-with-equal-number-rows-for-each-classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take equal no. of samples based on each class

```
df_cats = df[df['class'] == 'cat'][:200]
df_dogs = df[df['class'] == 'dog'][:200]
df_cows = df[df['class'] == 'cow'][:200]
```

Then concatenate dataframes

```
df_new = pd.concat([df_cats, df_dogs, df_cows])
```

From there split it into X and y

Answer (score 3):

You can `groupby` the "class" column, then you have a couple of options:

1. If you want to shuffle and select a random 200 of each, use `sample` aggregation.

   ```
   df.groupby('class').sample(200, random_state=42)
   ```
2. If shuffling isn't necessary, you just need the first 200 of each, use `head` aggregation.

   ```
   df.groupby('class').head(200)
   ```